# Spivak, Ch. 15, Problem 31: Prove that $\sin$ isn't defined implicitly by an algebraic equation. Understanding a step in the proof.

Tags: calculus, derivatives, proof-explanation, rational-functions, trigonometric-integrals

The following is a problem from Ch. 15 of Spivak's *Calculus*

> 31. (a) After all the work involved in the definition of $\sin$, it would be disconcerting to find that $\sin$ is actually a rational
>     function. Prove that it isn't. (There is a simple property of $\sin$
>     which a rational function cannot possibly have.).
>
> (b) Prove that $\sin$ isn't even defined implicitly by an algebraic
> equation. That is, there do not exist rational functions
> $f_0,...,f_{n-1}$ such that
>
> $$(\sin x)^n+f_{n-1}(x)(\sin x)^{n-1}+...+f_0(x)=0,\text{ for all }
> > x\tag{1}$$
>
> Hint: Prove that $f_0=0$, so that $\sin{x}$ can be factored out. The
> remaining factor is $0$ except perhaps at multiples of $\pi$. But this
> implies that it is $0$ for all $x$ (**Why?**) You are now set up for a
> proof by induction.

**My question is precisely the one in bold above.**

[It has been asked before here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/306464/sine-not-a-rational-function-spivak), but the answer there is but a hint that is already contained in the solution manual.

**Here is how the question arises in the context of a proof of part $(b)$.**

$(a)$

A rational function has a finite number of roots (unless it is zero everywhere). $\sin$ has infinite roots $$\sin{k\pi}=0,k\in\mathbb{Z}$$

and $\sin$ is not $0$ everywhere. Thus $\sin$ is not a rational function.

$(b)$

$$x=k\pi\implies\sin(k\pi)=0$$

So the entire expression $(1)$ becomes just $f_0(k\pi)=0$ for all $k\in\mathbb{Z}$. But $f_0$ is a rational function so it must be $0$, otherwise it'd have infinite roots.

Then $(1)$ becomes

$$\sin{x}[ (\sin{x})^{n-1}+f_{n-1}(x)(\sin{x})^{n-2}+...+f_1(x) ]=0\tag{2}$$

Now $x\neq k\pi, k\in\mathbb{Z}\implies\sin{x}\neq 0$, so the expression in brackets must equal zero.

**So here is the part that my question is about.**

We have

$$(\sin{x})^{n-1}+f_{n-1}(x)(\sin{x})^{n-2}+...+f_1(x)=0\tag{3}$$

Here is what the solution manual says at this point

> The term in brackets is continuous and $0$ except perhaps at multiples
> of $2\pi$, so it is $0$ everywhere.

This doesn't explain why.

$(3)$ is true for all $x\neq k\pi$, but possibly not at $x=k\pi$.

Rational functions can also be undefined at a finite number of points, but I believe this case is ruled out for any points because $(1)$ is true for all $x$, correct?

Ie, even at points $x=k\pi$, the lefthand expression in $(3)$ must at least be defined for $(2)$ and thus $(1)$ to be true, correct?

Therefore, the rational functions in question are continuous everywhere, $\sin$ and powers of $\sin$ are continuous everywhere, and so the expression in $(3)$ is continuous everywhere.

But if we assume that the lefthand expression in $(3)$ is anything other than $0$ at $k\pi$, then it is discontinuous at such points, which is a contradiction.

**I think the general idea is on the right track, but I don't feel very comfortable with the details of this last part.**

So, going back to original the problem statement: Why?

Comment: I think your general idea is correct. The detail here would be that if it was non-zero at some $k\pi$, then you could find a nbhd around $k\pi$ in which it was non-zero due to continuity. That would be a contradiction. This addresses your initial "Why?". As for the rest of the questions where you asked for your reasoning to be confirmed correct; they seem to be fine.

Comment: You're probably way beyond this comment being useful to *you*, but for anyone else: the handling of the $0$'s of the rational functions' denominators is vague on Spivak's end. Whether $\forall x$ means "$\forall x \in \mathbb R$" or "$\forall x$ that satisfy this equation", it matters not. Suppose there *are* holes (i.e. $x$'s where the equation is not defined).

Comment: Then, by definition of a polynomial, we know that there can only be finitely many holes across all $f_i$. Because there are only finitely many holes, we know that there is a 'largest' $x$ such that the equation is undefined. Choose a $k\pi \gt x_{\text{largest}}$. Suppose at this value the bracketed term does not evaluate to $0$. Then we still arrive at the same contradiction.